# Unable to publish an image using cvbridge

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, cvbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to create a simple image publisher from OpenCV to ROS, I am following the given tutorial.
http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython

However, when I run the program I get the following error:

ROS distribution: Kinetic Kame
OpenCV: 3.4.0

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/deepak/catkin_ws/src/python_learning/src/scripts/image_pub.py", line 40, in <module> main() File "/home/deepak/catkin_ws/src/python_learning/src/scripts/image_pub.py", line 36, in main image_publisher_obj.img_pub_node() File "/home/deepak/catkin_ws/src/python_learning/src/scripts image_pub.py", line 24, in img_pub_node ros_img = self.cvbridge_obj.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_img, encoding="bgr8")    File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv_bridge/core.py", line 246, in cv2_to_imgmsg raise TypeError('Your input type is not a numpy array') TypeError: Your input type is not a numpy array
```

My code is:

```
class ImagePublisher:
""" Class to define member functions for image publisher """

def __init__(self):
    """ Constructor """
    self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_pub_topic", img,queue_size=200)
    self.cvbridge_obj = CvBridge()

def img_pub_node(self):
    """ Publisher helper function """
    cv_img = cv2.imread('sizeDetect.jpg')
    
    # Convert this to ROS image format
    ros_img = self.cvbridge_obj.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_img, encoding="bgr8")
    try:
        self.image_pub.publish(ros_img)
        rate = rospy.Rate(10)
        rate.sleep()
    except CvBridgeError as bridgerr:
        print(bridgerr)

def main():
    "Main function"
    image_publisher_obj = ImagePublisher()
    rospy.init_node('img_pub_node', anonymous=True)
    image_publisher_obj.img_pub_node()
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My understanding is that OpenCV in Python will return numpy array and C++ will return Mat class. Then why is he complaining that it is not a numpy array.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281965/unable-to-publish-an-image-using-cvbridge/) by [dpakshimpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33391/dpakshimpo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2018-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpakshimpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33391/dpakshimpo/) on 2018-02-07**:
P.S: I also tried converting the cv_img object as a numpy array before passing to cv2_to_imgmsg, however, then it fails with the error -

```
~/cv_bridge/core.py", line 248, in cv2_to_imgmsg 
img_msg.height = cvim.shape[0]  IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-07**:
What does `print cv_img` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most likely explanation is that `cv_img = cv2.imread('sizeDetect.jpg')` failed to load sizeDetect.jpg because it isn't in the same path as where the script is being run from, and cv_img is `None`.  imread doesn't throw when it fails, just returns None.

If sizeDetect.jpg is in the same package as your python script you could use rospack like this:

```
import rospkg

...
    rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
    image_path = rospack.get_path('my_package_name') + '/images/'
    cv_img = cv2.imread(image_path + 'sizeDetect.jpg')
```

This is a complete example:

https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_textured_quads/blob/image_topic/tests/display_images_test.py

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpakshimpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33391/dpakshimpo/) on 2018-02-08**:
Thank you so much lucasw. It solved the problem. It looks stupid in hindsight, that I did not think of this :)
I still gave the full path in my code instead of using rospack. I am sure, rospack is the right way to go about in real world.